# How to create this borderstyle WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, border

How to create FormBorderStyle with transparency like here:
[image: Form border style]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is part of the OS. It is called `Aero`.  If the graphics card isnt capable of running `Aero`, then you won't get that style of window.  Another thing to note is that your application will look different on Windows XP, compared to Vista and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Aero theme + transparency on Windows XP too - Adam Nathan's book on WPF explains it in good detail, a quick search for Aero Theme on XP pointed to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2006/04/18/578637.aspx).

[image: Aero Theme on XP]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to use the Windows API for that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163435.aspx explains that you need to use DWM.
Here is some more code for it http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/AeroGlassForms.aspx